# How can I place dynamic controls on dynamic forms?

Tags: c#, dynamic-controls, dynamic-forms

I am trying to make custom forms with unique sets of controls on each form...  I can create the dynamic form, but I can't seem to put any controls on it..

```
using (Form formA = new Form())
{
  Button btn = new Button();
  formA.Text = "Form A";
  formA.Name = "FormA";
  this.MaximizeBox = false;
  this.MinimizeBox = false;
  this.BackColor = Color.White;
  this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
  this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(155, 265);
  this.Text = "Run-time Controls";
  this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
  this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
  formA.Show();
  formA.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

The form creates ok, but no luck on the buttons...  (I edited the code displayed here, to make it easier to see what I am trying to do, but my form still destroys itself as soon as it is created.  I have no idea why.

Comment: How can you tell?  The form is disposed of immediately after adding *one* button and after the form was shown.

Comment: What am I doing wrong?  I changed the formA.ShowDialog() to formA.Show(), and now I see the form destructing immediately, but I have no Idea why that is happening...  BTW I would like to thank everyone who took the time to point out how horrible I am at this...  Thank you for your support.

Comment: You are disposing the form with the **using()** function. Whatever resource is occupied into the **using()** enclose will be disposed as soon as it finises its enclosed statements.

Comment: I have it now.   Thank you for your help,  Engr Syed Rowshan Ali.

Comment: Never use a piece of code that you dont understand how it works.  If you dont know what `using` does, look it up, the documentation is online and free.

Comment: Today I have a better understanding of 'using' and of the process I was trying to figure out from the "code that I don't understand" @Pongjardenlarp.  If I followed your advice what would I have learned?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the following:

```
Button btn = new Button();
Form formA = new Form();
formA.Text = "Form A";
formA.Name = "FormA";
this.MaximizeBox = false;
this.MinimizeBox = false;
this.BackColor = Color.White;
this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(155, 265);
this.Text = "Run-time Controls";
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
formA.Show();
formA.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Answer (score -1):

First the `formA.ShowDialog();` will freeze there until the form is closed. Second the button you created only one and moved it around.

Change with the following :

```
using (Form formA = new Form()) 
{
   formA.Text = "Form A";
   formA.Name = "FormA";
   this.MaximizeBox = false;
   this.MinimizeBox = false;
   this.BackColor = Color.White;
   this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
   this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(155, 265);
   this.Text = "Run-time Controls";
   this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
   this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
   formA.Show();

   for (int x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
   {
      Button btn = new Button();
      btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10 + (x * 5), 10 + (x * 5));
      btn.Text = "Button" + x.ToString();
      btn.Name = "Button_" + x.ToString(); 
      formA.Controls.Add(btn);
   }
}
```